# Relationship between rank and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and rank of $A$ be $r$. If we multiply 2 to every row. What will the new determinant be? $2^r |A|$ or $2^n |A|$

I can understand why $2^n |A|$ is the answer but is $2^r |A|$ also correct?

Comment: A square matrix has nonzero determinant iff it is of full rank, so if $r\lt n$, then $|A|=0$ and consequently $2^r|A|=0$. Obviously, when $A$ is of full rank, then $r=n$ and both $2^r|A|$ and $2^n|A|$ are the same.

Comment: Hello :) If $r<n$, we have $\det(A) =0$, which leads to $\det(2A) =0=0\cdot 2^r$. If $r=n$, we have $\det(2A) =2^n\det(A) =2^r\det(A) $. In both cases your claim is correct.

Comment: If $A$ does not have full rank then $|A| = 0$ and so $0 = 2^n|A| = 2^r|A|$. If $A$ does have full rank then $n = r$ and so $2^n = 2^r$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.